# How to disable session/admin password for printing?

Tags: 11.04, password, printing

Each time i print, the session password is required. How to disable it ?

Comment: How did you configure your printer? Any proprietary drivers installed for root only?

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/57493/save-print-server-authentication-credentials/112872#112872

Answer (score 1):

You may want to review the setup procedures for printing and permissions:

[Local Printer](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/printing-setup.html)

[Default Printer](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/printing-setup-default-printer.html)

[Further Reading](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/hardware.html#printing) Which includes Bluetooth

[Network printing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu)