# Save print server authentication credentials

Tags: authentication, printing

At my work, I print through a print server.

My */etc/cups.d/client.conf* file is:

```
ServerName the.appropriate.server.location
```

With this configuration I have to log in with a username and a password every time I have to print (and even twice each time, the first time to get the printer settings, and the second time to effectively print).

I precise that I am usually printing via *Evince* (since I print PDF files and Evince is my favorite PDF viewer).

- How can I avoid logging in twice?
- Is it possible not to have to log in, even once, at each printing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get rid of the "Authentication Required to Print" dialog this is done by directly editing the file, `/etc/cups/printers.conf` as follows:

1. Open a terminal window:
2. Stop the cups server:
   `sudo service cups stop`
3. Edit the printers.conf file.

`sudo gedit /etc/cups/printers.conf`

Near the top of file `/etc/cups/printers.conf` is a line:

**AuthInfoRequired username,password**

Insert a "#" char in the first column (or, just delete the line):

`#AuthInfoRequired username,password`

1. Save edited file
2. Restart cups server:

`sudo service cups start`

This should fix the problem.

[Reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1211404)

Comment: If there are multiple printers the AuthInfoRequired should be commented out for each

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `system-config-printer`

**2)** Click on "Add" button and choose your printer.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think this answers my question. Actually, if I open system-config-printer, I see the printer I use. This printer is on a Print Server which asks for authentication. Thus each time I want to print, I have to authenticate with a username and a password. And each time, I have to authenticate twice since Evince first needs to know the settings of the printer (paper size for instance), and then I re-authenticate when I effectively print. My question is: Is there a way to avoid these authentications, just as with ssh for instance. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm sorry. This steps worked for me, I don't have to authenticate. I will do some research trying to help you more.

Comment: Can you authenticate at command line? I'm thinking you could make an script to do this automatically.

Comment: If I use lpr at command line for instance, I get a prompt to authenticate. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem here, I will continue to try...

Comment: I haven't the configuration file you've mentioned above `/etc/cups.d/client.conf`, may be trying the steps I posted could give us another result?