# Is there a way to save username and password for print authentication?

Tags: networking, printing, authentication

I saw this [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57493/save-print-server-authentication-credentials) and followed its answer, but the problem persists for me. Once I send a document to print, this dialog box (in figure) opens up and shows "Held for authentication". Then I right-click and enter my username and password and then the pdf is sent to the network printer. [image: Authentication]

Is there a way to store my username and password? The 'Remember password' option does not work. I do not want to remove authentication (can't see how the network printer will identify me if I am not authenticated, as the network is based on Windows), I just want to save my username and password into some appropriate file so that I do not have to key in every time.

Comment: Does "Remember password" not work? Do you search a program to save passwords?

Comment: No, it doesn't, unfortunately. Instead of a program for doing pwds (I do not know about them), I thought I could save in some text file from which this program collects its data.

Comment: Is the username/password to your local machine or to the printer itself?

Comment: @David: It is the network printer and I have to log in with my network username and password.

Comment: can you change your local password to be the same as the network one

Comment: @jet: the passwords are the same, but that's irrelevant as the Network runs on Windows...

Answer (score 1):

that's a bug, look at [bugs.launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/445333)

on [another page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/475686) they write:

> If I don't type anything, the window's form says that I will send my username only (and a blank password) but wireshark shows that it is instead sending the correct username and password (which I entered into the printers folder, but which is hidden).

maybe it works for you

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Although you are not sharing a printer on your computer the fact that you install Samba and connect to a share on your network means you might get authentication via Samba. I haven't tried it personally but its worth a shot.

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-printserver.html